# Can't create a maven project in Eclipse

Tags: maven

When I attempt to create a Maven project in eclipse (selected maven-archetype-quickstart, version 1.4)  I am getting the following error:

Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:3.0.2
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:3.0.2

I am really new to maven, I am just trying to setup a project to use for cucumber.  Any advise is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be something like this?
[Maven error - can't create Maven project in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54348492/maven-error-cant-create-maven-project-in-eclipse)
I'm trying to resolve the same issue but nothing worked yet for me,,

context:
I use maven daily and never had this until 2 days back till now. I did reinstall my computer two weeks back and the maven, jdk, eclipse and all come back from an old backup