# Maven error - can't create Maven project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

After try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076179/pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requ) getting below error

[image: Getting this error]

Log Shows:

> Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:1.0 from any of the configured repositories.
>   Could not resolve artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:1.0
>   **Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:1.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out**
>   Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:1.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out

But in traffic it's showing HTTP 200 PFB

> [25/Jan/2019:17:40:20 +0530] "GET https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/pl/project13/maven/git-commit-id-plugin/2.2.5/git-commit-id-plugin-2.2.5.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 108711 200 108711 0 0 275 573 222 540 0

Proxy settings.xml:

```
    <settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                              http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <proxies>
        <proxy>
            <active>true</active>
            <protocol>http</protocol>
            <host>***</host>
            <port>8080</port>
            <username>***</username>
            <password>***</password>
        </proxy>

    </proxies>
</settings>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Without knowing what "all possibilities" you got are...tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25911623/problems-using-maven-and-ssl-behind-proxy

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["PKIX path building failed" and "unable to find valid certification path to requested target"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076179/pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requ)

Comment: @kapex thanks for your time , but it didn't solve my problem completely.